# Vuetify adding style on v-slot:label

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-slot

I have Vuetify code which look like this

```
<v-radio-group v-model="gender" column class="radio-group-full-width">
  <v-radio value="Boy">
    <template v-slot:label>
      <v-textarea
        v-model="answer"
        v-validate="'required'"
        required
        :error-messages="
          errors.collect('form-create.answer')
        "
        label="Answer 1"
        data-vv-name="answer"
        type="text"
      ></v-textarea>
    </template>
  </v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

The Problem is that i want to have the text-area in full width, but the label tag which is generated by vuetify template slot blocks this. Do you have any ideas how i could fix this?

[What it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV6Zu.png)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m1LJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

answer worked for me with a slight modification to the braces:

```
.radio-full-width >>> label {
  width: 100%;
}
```